# Is there a more compact way to serialize a JavaScript object with duplicate object values?

Tags: javascript, json

Say, that I create a JavaScript object in the following manner:

```
var helloWorld = {"hello": "world"};
var obj = {"a": helloWorld, "b": helloWorld};
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to serialize this object in a compact way. If I use `JSON.stringify`, then `helloWorld` is in the resulting representation, in its entirety, multiple times:

```
JSON.stringify(obj); // {"a":{"hello":"world"},"b":{"hello":"world"}}
```

Is there any standard way to serialize this object which results in a more compact representation?

Comment: I hope the duplicate I've chosen answers your question, even if the question is not the same.

Comment: Like what do you mean as "compact way"? Why do you need compact representation of JSON if you can configure GZIP encoding for requests?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, it seems that is essentially the same question.